# Search not working in hugo when i deploy website online

Tags: search, hugo

I have a problem the search bar works locally in the address localhost:1313 but does not work when I deploy my site online !

Do you have any solutions ?

PS: i use hugo framework

Comment: Without code or a repo we cannot help you!