# My Hugo blog's search isn't working. Not sure what needs to be done

Tags: search, hugo, hugo-config

I'm using Hugo [paperMod theme](https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod/tree/exampleSite). I read online to open the console. When I do that upon sharing I see the following error.

[image]

That implies that an `index.json` is missing somewhere. I don't know how to find it or point to it.

Also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76249270/search-not-working-in-hugo-when-i-deploy-website-online) question without an answer.

In my [config file](https://github.com/mfaani/mfaani/blob/0fa88899afe8efedb1f3b167aba77e4821d12aee/config.yml) I don't see anything related to search. Nor anything in the [config](https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod/blob/exampleSite/config.yml) file of papermod's example site.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the right path.

Hugo can typically generate your content in a variations of forms. See docs: [Custom Output formats | Hugo](https://gohugo.io/templates/output-formats/)

If you specify json as well, then it will create it for you.

See my updated [`config.yml`](https://github.com/mfaani/mfaani/blob/526f70f6d3d72dfa0cd5f8c31ddcdfde4ceda812/config.yml) file. I was missing `JSON` from my outputs. Adding that, fixed my search functionality.

```
# needed to ensure different manifestations of the site work. 
outputs:
  home:
  # To create webpages. 
    - HTML
  # To create RSS Feed
    - RSS
  # To create an index.json so search works on the site
    - JSON
```

After doing such my search worked. I was also able to find `index.json` at `https://mfaani.com/index.json`

Note: for your theme things could be different, but you get the idea.